# How do I add 2 numbers in an IF statement for bash scripting?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

So I'm just trying to run a check that deletes folders that are less than or equal to current hour by 3 hours, but I get an "integer expression expected" error.

```
if [ ${currentFileHour[$i]}+3 -le 19  ]
```

If I were to write it in javascript as a quick example it would be

```
if(5 + 6 <= 10){
    console.log('yes')
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `${currentFileHour[$i]}`. And if it's an integer, the expression should be `[ $(( ${currentFileHour[$i]}+3 )) -le 19 ]`

Comment: @guillermochamorro you are the man guillermo!

Answer (score 4):

bash has an arithmetic conditional construct (see [Conditional Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs) in the manual)

```bsh
if (( "${currentFileHour[$i]}" + 3 <= 19 )); then ...
```

In an arithmetic context in bash, you can omit the `$`, which for array elements would look like:

```bsh
if (( currentFileHour[$i] + 3 <= 19 )); then ...
```

and assuming that's an indexed array, the index is arithmetic, so

```bsh
if (( currentFileHour[i] + 3 <= 19 )); then ...
```

Demo:

```bsh
$ i=10
$ currentFileHour[i]=16
$ if (( currentFileHour[i] + 3 <= 19 )); then echo yes; fi
yes
```

One thing to be careful about concerning hours (and minutes and seconds, etc) is invalid octal numbers:

```bsh
$ currentFileHour[i]="08"
$ if (( currentFileHour[i] + 3 <= 19 )); then echo yes; fi
bash: ((: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
```

The leading zero makes bash think you want octal.

To get around that:

- for the `date` command, use `%_H` which pads with a space instead of a zero, or `%-H` which does not pad single digit hours, or
- tell bash arithmetic that it's a base-10 number with a "10#" prefix (need the `$` in this case)

  ```bsh
  $ if (( 10#${currentFileHour[i]} + 3 <= 19 )); then echo yes; fi
  yes
  ```